# Select as boolean using PostgreSQL 'crypt()' function

Tags: java, postgresql, jooq

I'm trying to replicate the following SQL query using jOOQ, and I'm running into some errors. I'm want to see if a direct replacement is possible, before re-working the query if required, so just looking for some advice.

```
SELECT
    user_password_hash = crypt(?, user_password_hash) AS is_password_match
    roles
FROM system_users
WHERE user_name = ?;
```

I've tried the following jOOQ replacement, though it has compile errors:

```
DSL.using(connection, SQLDialect.POSTGRES)
    .select(SYSTEM_USERS.USER_PASSWORD_HASH.equal(crypt(password, SYSTEM_USERS.USER_PASSWORD_HASH.getName())), SYSTEM_USERS.ROLES)
    .from(SYSTEM_USERS)
    .where(SYSTEM_USERS.USER_NAME.equal(userName));
```

I believe the problem is the first part of the #select() call is being resolved as a Condition, rather than a Field. But I'm not sure how best to use the #equal() call to make it a Field.

Does anyone have any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DSL.field(Condition)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#field(org.jooq.Condition)) to turn a `Condition` into a `Field<Boolean>`